# Need help identifying dups in the table

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, amazon-redshift

## What I have:

1. `data_source_1` table
2. `data_source_2` table
3. `data_sources_view` view

## About tables:

#### `data_source_1`:

has no dups:

```
db=# select count(*) from (select distinct * from data_source_1);
count 
--------
543243
(1 row)

db=# select count(*) from (select * from data_source_1);
count 
--------
543243
(1 row)
```

#### `data_source_2`:

has no dups:

```
db=# select count(*) from (select * from data_source_2);
count 
-------
5304
(1 row)

db=# select count(*) from (select distinct * from data_source_2);
count 
-------
5304
(1 row)
```

#### `data_sources_view`:

has dups:

```
db=# select count(*) from (select distinct * from data_sources_vie);
count 
--------
538714
(1 row)

db=# select count(*) from (select * from data_sources_view);
count 
--------
548547
(1 row)
```

The view is simple as:

```
CREATE VIEW data_sources_view
AS SELECT * 
FROM (
      (
       SELECT a, b, 'data_source_1' as source
       FROM data_source_1
      )
      UNION ALL 
      ( 
       SELECT a, b, 'data_source_2' as source
       FROM data_source_2
      )
);
```

## What I want to know:

- How is that possible to have dups in a view where source tables doesn't have dups + `'data_source_x' as source` eliminates the possibility of overlapping data.
- How to identify dups?

## What I've tried:

```
db# create table t1 as select * from data_sources_view;
SELECT
db=# 
db=# create table t2 as select distinct * from data_sources_view;
SELECT
db=# create table t3 as select * from t1 minus select * from t2;
SELECT
db=# select 't1' as table_name, count(*) from t1 UNION ALL
db-# select 't2' as table_name, count(*) from t2 UNION ALL
db-# select 't3' as table_name, count(*) from t3;
table_name | count 
------------+--------
t1 | 548547
t3 | 0
t2 | 538714
(3 rows)
```

## Database:

Redshift (`PostgreSQL`)

Comment: To identify duplicates simply do a `select a,b,source from data_sources_view group by a,b,source having count(*) > 1;`

Comment: That's pretty close,  I got `9657` thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is because your data sources have more than two columns.  If you do these counts:

```
select count(*) from (select distinct a, b from data_source_1);
```

and

```
select count(*) from (select distinct a, b from data_source_2);
```

You should find that they are different from the `count(*)` you get on the same table.

Answer (score 0):

UNION vs UNION ALL

1. UNION - If the data exist in the TOP Query it's suppressed in the bottom query.

OUTPUT

FOO

2. UNION ALL - The data repeats as the data exist in both tables (shows both records)

OUTPUT

FOO

FOO